# Create a new folder by merging two folders with subfolder

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder with this format

> +Home_Directory
>
> ++folder1
>
> ```
>  ++subfolder1
>
>  ++subfolder2
> ```
>
> ++folder2
>
> ```
>  ++subfolder1
>
>  ++subfolder2
> ```

I want to create a new folder and merge these two folder together with the subfolder two create something like this

> +Home_Directory
>
> ++merge_folder
>
> ```
>  ++merge_subfolder1
>
>  ++merge_subfolder2
> ```

Comment: Use `os.listdir()` and iterate over the result, assemble the full file path using `os.path.join()` and then do `shutil.move()`. You can also integrate an `os.path.exists()` check to handle possible merge conflicts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.